# get rid of centered play button from youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm using the google youtube chromless api to create custom play controls for yotube vids on my site. Using the chromless player doesn't seem to get rid of the play icon that sits over the video at the start. I cant hide all the other controls using this:

```
 swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1", Id, "545", "300", "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

Googled this to death but can't find the answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: NO neither can I! Thanks for looking all the same

Comment: Me neither, which probably means we can't...